# Hyperledger SDK for Java chaincode (shim-client-1.0)

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I tried to compile chaincode sample and write my own one (https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/tree/master/examples/chaincode/java/SimpleSample)

However, I can't get a shim-client-1.0. Do you have plans to make java sdk public?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope that “shim-client-1.0.jar” will be added to maven repository soon, nevertheless you can try to compile it using source code in “github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim/java”.

```
gradle build
```

and "shim-client-1.0.jar" will be available in github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim/java/build/lib folder.

Comment: I'm doing this, and I got this: You are using Gradle 4.4.1:  This version of the protobuf plugin works with Gradle version 2.12+. Any suggestions? Should I try with 2.12?

Comment: Is it still not uploaded to Maven?