# How do you run the fabric-java-sdk 1.0.1 end to end test?

Tags: java, hyperledger-fabric

As described on page https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java
In a Cygwin terminal I built the Ubuntu virtual image from Hyperledger Fabric 1.0.2 sources, built the fabric Docker images and launched fabric in a terminal with the following:

```
cd /cygdrive/c/gocode
mkdir fabric_1.0.2
cd fabric_1.0.2

# get the sources to build VM in which we will build the Docker images
git clone  https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric.git
git clone  https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca.git

# update the sources to latest version 1.0.2 tag
cd  fabric-ca
git reset --hard cb117d85980799d24d6df2d3533f5598a552b259
cd ../fabric
git reset --hard 5fb31ddd24d6441b0d499b9bb211632800044512

# change to sub-folder where Vagrantfile is
cd devenv

# launch VM, it will update itself and install dependencies as per 
# setup.sh referred to in Vagrantfile
vagrant up

# in case something kernel-related was updated:
vagrant reload 

# log in to image:
vagrant ssh

# build fabric docker images
make docker

# build fabric-ca docker images
cd ../fabric-ca
make docker

exit
vagrant halt

# For fabric-java-sdk testing, add in Vagrantfile:
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 7056, host: 7056
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 7058, host: 7058
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 8051, host: 8051
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 8053, host: 8053
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 8054, host: 8054
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 8056, host: 8056
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 8058, host: 8058
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 7059, host: 7059

# Add in Vagrantfile between the two lines:
#####config.vm.synced_folder "..", "/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric"
config.vm.synced_folder "fabric-sdk-java/src/test/fixture/sdkintegration", "/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/sdkintegration"
#####config.vm.synced_folder ENV.fetch('LOCALDEVDIR', ".."), "#{LOCALDEV}"

# under /cygdrive/c/gocode/fabric_1.0.2/fabric/devenv    
git clone https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java.git
cd fabric-sdk-java
# reset to latest version 1.0.1
git reset --hard 11bd160a95fa8529d93582ec68556bb1c4652c21

vagrant up
vagrant box update
vagrant reload
vagrant ssh

# add JAVA_HOME environment variable
sudo vi /etc/profile
# add two lines:
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

exit
vagrant ssh

# test we have our variable, Java and Maven:
echo $JAVA_HOME
java -version
mvn -version

cd sdkintegration
# launches fabric:
docker-compose down;  rm -rf /var/hyperledger/*; docker-compose up --force-recreate
```

Next I built some of the fabric-java-sdk artefacts with the following steps, all successful:

```
# open a new Cygwin terminal:
cd /cygdrive/c/gocode/fabric_1.0.2/fabric/devenv
vagrant ssh

# build the jar /vagrant/fabric-sdk-java/target/fabric-sdk-java-1.0.1.jar
cd /vagrant/fabric-sdk-java
mvn install

#### at this point in the other terminal with fabric running, 
#### the following lines appear:
## peer0.org1.example.com    | 2017-09-21 13:56:57.747 UTC [endorser] ProcessProposal -> DEBU 1a6 Entry
## peer0.org1.example.com    | 2017-09-21 13:56:57.747 UTC [protoutils] ValidateProposalMessage -> DEBU 1a7 ValidateProposalMessage starts for signed proposal 0xc4202bb680
## peer0.org1.example.com    | 2017-09-21 13:56:57.747 UTC [endorser] ProcessProposal -> DEBU 1a8 Exit

# build /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim/java/build/libs/shim-client-1.0.jar
cd /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim/java
gradle build

cd /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/sdkintegration/javacc/example_cc
# ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39519586/shim-client-1-0-jar-missing-when-compiling-the-java-chain-code
gradle -b build.gradle build

# add missing dependency in pom.xml:
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0-M1</version>
</dependency>

mvn dependency:resolve
mvn install
```

At this point I am both stuck and confused by the documentation. What do I need to do next to run the end to end Java integration test, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a bounty on it for a full day, I am amazed no one ran off with it.

The answer was on my old blog post at https://bertrandszoghy.wordpress.com/2017/05/12/fabric-sdk-java/

All that was missing in the second terminal window was:

```
cd /vagrant/fabric-sdk-java
mvn failsafe:integration-test -DskipITs=false
```

Results :
Tests run: 18, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 2